# Convert system date into est time zone and compare two dates

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

In my application I am getting a json where i have a date string. I have requirement for comparing this date with current date and time in EST timezone format.
My input date is Tue Jun 23 2015 11:57:00
and my current date should be in the same format but in est time zone

I have to compare both of those.

Comment: Check out moment.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the server time and compare with yours like that

```
function convertToServerTimeZone(){
   //EST
    var offset = -5.0
    var clientDate = new Date();
    var yourInputDate = new Date("Tue Jun 23 2015 11:57:00");
    var utc = clientDate.getTime() + (clientDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var serverDate = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
    var dateFormated = serverDate.toISOString().substr(0,10);
    var dateFormatedYourDate = yourInputDate.toISOString().substr(0,10);
    if(dateFormated > dateFormatedYourDate){
       //here to compare string values
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to compare. Actually i am new to javascript so dont have that much idea

Comment: Will that also compare the time, because what i feel is it only compares the date.